# how to remove csrfmiddlewaretoken in django GET or POST

Tags: python, django

I using a hash code and md5 for an merchant API, in my PHP it is running smoothly and I was able to convert the code in django python but whenever I tried the transaction for merchant I always get this error.

```
E5000: Cannot form a matching secure hash based on the merchant's request using either of the two merchant's secrets
```

I think that the `csrfmiddlewaretoken` interrupt the GET/POST of the merchant...

Now, It is possible that I can remove `csrfmiddlewaretoken` GET/POST from specific template or method in views.py?

Comment: Django has several decorators one of which is csrf_exempt. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt. If the problem persists there maybe an error in the code conversion.

Comment: Can you please show the code where you output the form?